# Simulink Matlab function block deleting rows from a vector

Tags: function, vector, simulink

That i want to do is to delete certain rows (or columns doesn't really mater...) from a given vector.
By going through Simulink's components found out that there is nothing performing such an operation,there are blocks help one add elements but nothing clearly for removing,so ended up trying to delete them by using a function block and following the online examples that demonstrate the usage of "[]".Lets say that i want to delete the second column of the vector u,i do u(:, 2) = [];.
That works absolutely fine in a separate m file or function but unfortunately not in a function block returning: 
"Simulink does not have enough information to determine output sizes for
this block. If you think the errors below are inaccurate, try specifying
types for the block inputs and/or sizes for the block outputs."
and:
Size mismatch (size [4 x 4] ~= size [4 x 3]).
The size to the left is the size of the left-hand side of the assignment.
Function 'MATLAB Function' (#107.41.42), line 4, column 1:
"u"
Launch diagnostic report.

Is there any alternative you can suggest to remove several elements in a given vector in Simulink?
Thanks in advance
George

Comment: Can you post all the code you used in MATLAB function block and the input size you tried, so we can repeat the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,managed to do it without function block.There is a much easier way,by using Pad,and defining the output vector to be shorter than the input resulting in truncation.